# What's the syntax to query data from an ODBC (excel table) from another Data Connection (sql)?

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2012, odbc

Good day,
I've got the following basic stuff (I hope not too basic). Correct me where it's not right.

For querying a table within the **same database** I understand can be used:

```
SELECT <field>
FROM <table>
WHERE <condition>
```

When querying a table in **another DB** within the same server I understand that can be used:

```
SELECT <field>
FROM [database].<table>
WHERE <condition>
```

When querying a table in another DB in **another server** I understand that can be used:

```
SELECT <field>
FROM [server\instance].[database].<table>
WHERE <condition>
```

QUESTION: ***What's the correct syntax to successfully query data from a ODBC connection (excel file) in another connection (sql)?***

In VS2012 I've got the following DB, (in which I opened a query):

> [serverName\sqlexpress].[DBname].dbo

Also I've opened the following ODBC connection:

> ODBC.EXCEL.[localPath]\[fileName].xls

My intention is to populate a DB table from an excel ODBC data.

I've attempted to copy the entire ODBC string as the server name, but an error was thrown.

If can be provided an entire query script to do so in the form:

```
SELECT <fields>
INTO <sql db table>
FROM <ODBC table>
```

would be very much appreciated.
Thanks for your attention.